# Comparing two identical surveys from 2019 and 2023. Each question has multiple items including "don't know"

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, likert, frequency

I have this dataset made up of several questions, each with ordinal answers (likert-like) which unfortunately include a "don't know" option. The dataset is split in two: one portion from year 2019, one from year 2023. The samples are independet (no way to know these are the same people that answered the first survey)

As the questions and items are identical, I tried to compare the frequency distributions of the answers (freq tables grouped barplots). How can I test these data for significance?

Comment: Welcome to cv! What would be wrong about treating "I don't know" as a separate category? // Do you plan to investigate the relation between answers to different questions from the same person, or just treat all questions separately?